# adb push not working on MacBook Pro M2 Max (Apple Silicon)

Tags: android, adb, apple-silicon, apple-m2, macbookpro

I have successfully installed `adb` and also got the devices list after the command `adb devices`.

But when I try to push a folder via the command `adb push folder/ /sdcard/`, it gets stuck after 1-2 files and stays like that.

It is running fine on an Intel MacBook Pro.

Are there any prerequisites I need to do before using `adb` on Apple Silicon?

Comment: What MacOS versions do you have installed on the two systems? MacOS Ventura is known to have a very unstable USB connection to iPhones and other USB devices.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you did to get adb running in the first place? i currently have issues because my adb process gets killed all the time i try to start it.